# The 4 most significant bit in a jump instruction in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I understand that for J-format instructions, the 32-bit instruction is split into a 6-bit opcode and a 26-bit target address. By realising that the last 2 bits will always be 0 since jumps can only jump to word-aligned addresses, we are able to specify 28 out of the 32-bit address indirectly.

We are then told that to get the other 4 bits, MIPS chooses to take the 4 most significant bit from PC + 4. My question is that what if PC + 4 is so far ahead/behind, such that its 4 most significant bits are different from the 4 most significant bits of our intended destination, does that mean that we're unable to reach our intended destination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does that mean that we're unable to reach our intended destination?

Yes, you cannot reach all 32-bits of the address space with a J-type instruction.  Effectively, a statically linked code segment using `j` jumps is limited to 2<sup>28</sup> bytes in size, if you want to be able to jump from the beginning to the end or vice versa.

If you really want to reach anywhere in the address space, you'll need a jump register, `jr` (or `jalr`) and have the appropriate address in a register, which could be assembled using `lui`/`addi` pair, or loaded from data, as could be the case when using a function pointer.  For a 32-bit machine, these approaches can both reach any location in the address space.

Note that dynamically loaded libraries are typically each separately linked chunks of code, and inter-DLL invocations could be using `jr` in some way.

---

Also, to add to the discussion, RISC V does a much better job in this regard, having eliminated this approach to having 16 large code segments; plus, they added another counterpart to `lui`, namely `auipc` — that has the same usage as `lui` but computes a pc-relative value that can be used instead to make code more position independent; while the `jalr` instruction has been upgraded to have an immediate, so can be used in a 2 instruction sequence `auipc`; `jalr`.  Further, the RISC V toolchain supports linker relaxation, a complex mechanism that allows the linker to shorten code sequences at link time when they would reach with fewer instructions.

Comment: Technically 2^28 - 4 if you require that any instruction in the region can be a `j` to any other.  If the last word of the region is a `j`, it could only jump within the *next* region, not the one it's in.  (Because of the PC+4 carrying into the high bits).  Of course it could be a `b`-type instruction with a PC-relative displacement.  (A 2^28 byte region starting with the word before a 2^28-byte alignment boundary would have the opposite problem; other instructions couldn't `j` to it, although it could `j` to any other instruction.)

Comment: Also, for code near a 2^28 boundary (or in general), you can use `b` (aka `beq $zero,$zero` or equivalent) to unconditionally do a relative branch with +-2^17 byte range, instead of within any aligned boundary.

Comment: @Erik and @Peter, thanks for taking time out to respond! That is a lot more information than what I would've needed, I appreciate it :) Anyways, what if I use a sequence of ```j``` instructions, where one ```j``` reaches another ```j```. Would that work and is that even allowed? Sorry for the rookie question hahaha

Comment: @kingsbane: That will let you go *forwards* but not backwards.  e.g. a `j` instruction at the end of a 256MiB region can jump to the `j` at the end of the next 256MiB region (because it's region-absolute to the region containing PC+4, not to itself, i.e. to the branch delay slot).  But going backwards you can't get out of the 256 MiB region you're in.  You'd need `b` instructions as part of your chain.  But yes, it would work.

Comment: @kingsbane: But remember that real MIPS (not simplified academic versions) has a branch-delay slot, so executing a `j` at the end of a region means that the instruction at the start of the next region also executed before the jump is taken.  So you do need to put a `nop` or something there.  If you had a MIPS with virtual memory, that means your chain of jumps would include a page at the start and end of each 256 MiB region, not just the end.

Comment: @kingsbane:   (Although you could play virtual memory tricks and map all those pages to the same physical page which starts with a NOP and ends with a `j`.  The `j` would have the same machine-code encoding every time to reach the end of the next region.)  If you had a "simplified" MIPS with no branch-delay slot, like MARS simulates by default, `j` instructions can execute back to back (with stalls between if branch prediction didn't hide the branch latency) so yeah `j` instructions at the end of every 256MiB region could jump forwards to each other.  Much less efficient than `la`/`jr` :P